# Get non black pixels inside a circle openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get to count the non black pixels that are inside the circle of the right image(that has a mask applied) and divided by the total amount of pixels that are in the circle, but I don't find a way to only iterate over the pixels inside the circle.

[image]

My idea was this.

- The radius of the circle is 1324 pixels
- The center of the circle is at column 2184 and row 1456
- Since the image has an applied mask I iterate over all the pixels and I only count the pixels that are not black
- Divided the pixels I counted and divided by the area of the circle

But for some reason, I'm counting more pixels than needed
I'm new with OpenCV, so I don't have enough experience

My code:

```
def get_CCI(self):
    result = self.result_image()
    rows, cols, _= result.shape
    counter = 0
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            if all(result[r, c] != [0, 0, 0]):
                counter += 1
    
    return counter / self.__get_CircleArea()
```

Comment: See np.count_nonzero() at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html. Mask your image so that everything is black that you do to want. Then use np.count_nonzero(). Alternately, make sure the image is binary after masking. The get the mean of the image (see np.mean) and multiply that by the width*height (total pixels) to get the count of the non-black pixels.

Comment: I would like to hear more details: so, you have the planet, you apply a threshold? what information do you want to get from the selected image? Why do you want to count the non black pixels? If you could provide more details, you could get faster responses.